# Javascript getting stripped href values from children elements (without jquery) assign active class

Tags: javascript, html, nested, href, children

Idea: I Want to add class="active" to an li element, when specific link was clicked which is equal to the href and the url.

Problem: I can not select the href values which are nested inside a ul li. CSS might load the style to early.
Note: The html gets injected with php.

Code:

```js
window.onload = function () {
 
var curURL = window.location.href.split("/").pop(); //Outputs the current page url ex index.php

var linkNow = document.getElementsByClassName("topnav").getElementsByTagName("a").href;//Nesting this does not work but how can it be achieved?


//Loop check which curURL matches the href value, true->assign active class

for (var i = 0; i < link.length; i++) {
    if (curURL == linkNow[i]){
      linkNow.addClass("active");
      break;
    }
        
}

//As soon as the a element has the class="active" the navbar color will change
}
```

```html
<ul class='topnav'>
  <li><a href='index.php'>Home</a></li>
  <li><a href='news.php'>News</a></li>
  <li><a href='showcase.php'>Showcase</a></li>
  <li class='icon'>
    <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='myFunction()'>&#9000;</a><!-- responsive icon-->
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to say "no jQuery". There's no tag and it's not used in the OP so answers shouldn't use it.

Comment: Sorry about that. You see I researched a fair amount, and most answers were for jQuery, so I wanted to clarify ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to go about it, one is to use a selector to get the element directly, e.g.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var href = 'index.php';
  var link = document.querySelector('a[href="' + href + '"]');
  link.parentNode.className = 'active';
}
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class='topnav'>
  <li><a href='index.php'>Home</a></li>
  <li><a href='news.php'>News</a></li>
  <li><a href='showcase.php'>Showcase</a></li>
</ul>
```

To be compatible with older browsers, you could also use a more general selector like:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('ul a');
```

or even:

```
var links = document.links;
```

which is compatible with pretty much every browser ever, then loop over them looking for the appropriate *href* value.

Comment: OP wants the class on the `li`, not on the `a`

Comment: I liked the `'a[href="' + href + '"]'`, so obvious (when you see it) but rarely seen ... plus 1

Answer (score 0):

simple use with [**`queryselectorAll()`**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp). like this `document.querySelectorAll('.topnav li a')`

1. In your code `for loop length` use `linkNow` instead `link`
2. And apply with Matching if condition try this `(curURL == linkNow[i].href)`

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var curURL = window.location.href
  var linkNow = document.querySelectorAll('.topnav li a')
  for (var i = 0; i < linkNow.length; i++) {
    if (curURL == linkNow[i].href) {
      linkNow[i].classList.add("active");
      console.log(linkNow[i])
      break;
    }
    else{
     linkNow[i].classList.remove('active')
    
    }

  }
}
```

```css
.active{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul class='topnav'>
  <li><a href='index.php'>Home</a></li>
  <li><a href='news.php'>News</a></li>
  <li><a href='js'>Its for test only</a></li>
  
  <li><a href='showcase.php'>Showcase</a></li>
  <li class='icon'>
    <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='myFunction()'>&#9000;</a>
    <!-- responsive icon-->
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: OP wants the class on the `li`, not on the `a` ... I guess `.parentElement` will fix that

Comment: I actually do need the class to be on the a. When I display the source of the site, no class contains active.

Comment: Output on the page needs to be: <li><a class='active' href='index.php'>Home</a></li> Then my css kicks in and colors the link.

Comment: @E.Vox see the updated answer.If you need apply the class in `a` tag remove the `parentElement` in for loop and also remove the `split('/')` in `curURL`

Comment: @E.Vox i was added with working snippet . i was added  some html element for test purpose..

Comment: It legitimately works. Thank you very much. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

The key mistake here is that `getElementsByClassName` is returning an **array**. Notice the **s** in the function name?

So if you want to use this function remember to loop through the results.  I am just using `[0]` here for simple example.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var curURL = 'news.php';

  var lis = document.getElementsByClassName("topnav")[0].getElementsByTagName("li");

  for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    var a = lis[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (a.getAttribute("href") === curURL) { // using .getAttribute() to get raw value instead of full url
      //lis[i].classList.add("active"); //use this instead if you want to add class to <li>
      a.classList.add("active");  // be careful .addClass() is an jquery function
      break;
    }

  }
}
```

```css
li.active {
  background: red
}

a.active{
  color: yellow
}
```

```html
<ul class='topnav'>
  <li><a href='index.php'>Home</a></li>
  <li><a href='news.php'>News</a></li>
  <li><a href='showcase.php'>Showcase</a></li>
  <li class='icon'>
    <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='myFunction()'>&#9000;</a>
    <!-- responsive icon-->
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Mark Ni. This is working too. Favored this snippet since its a bit more compact.